# Twilio : Setting phone number for the outgoing call widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

In the below widget, the field NUMBER TO CALL cannot be edited.

[image]

So, how do we set the value of the phone number that needs to be called

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the `NUMBER TO CALL` in Twilio Studio for this case.

The `{{contact.channel.address}}` value comes in as the `To` parameter for the Trigger widget when you make the POST request to Studio's REST API.

So, you'll have to pass the number when you trigger the flow.

***Docs:*** (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#rest-api)