# "Number to Contact" does not send message when edited

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio

When I change the `{{contact.channel.address}}` number to a different number that I receive form `REST Parameters` the message will not send.

I am trying to take a `POST` request that then triggers the `Twilio Studio` to call a store and tell them they have a new online order. They then press Keys to indicate how long the order will take to process and then I send a message to the customer telling them when to pick up their order.

When I keep the `{{contact.channel.address}}` the same the code runs correctly but when I change this it doesn't work anymore.

Found this link that says it cannot be changed for `outbound call` but it is possible to edit for [send message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50744344/twilio-setting-phone-number-for-the-outgoing-call-widget)

Does anyone know can I do this or is this functionality not support at all?

```
 curl -X POST "URL" -d "To=+1xxxxxxxxxx" -d "From=+1xxxxxxxxxx" -d "Parameters={\"orderid\":\"12345\", \"name\":\"Johen\", \"phone\":\"+1xxxxxxxxxx\"}" -u SID:AUTH
```

[Studio Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vRfW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {{contact.channel.address}} should be equal to the To you pass in when calling the Studio REST Api URL. In your example, "To=+1xxxxxxxxxx".

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the response! Do you know if it possible to send messages not using this? i.e I need the "To=+1xxxxxxxxxx" for the first part of the flow but I need a different number for the final part which I am trying to get from the JSON parameters but it will not send when I change {{contact.channel.address}} to say {{contact.channel.phone}} where .phone is a different number. Sorry if this isn't very clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Number to Call in the Make Outgoing Call widget is a non-editable field (greyed out). I would have to say no, and that it must be passed in. So you have multiple Make Outgoing Call widgets in your flow, making calls to two different destinations?

Comment: From the Documentation, "The To must be the Contact's phone number and cannot be changed".

Make Outgoing Call
https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#make-outgoing-call

Is it possible to kick off a new Studio Flow using the Studio HTTP Request Widget, passing in the new To as a HTTP parameter used by the new flow and Make Outgoing Call widget.

Comment: Didn't know I could do this! Thanks for your help.